# AWS Cloud 9 - Run is not launching website

Tags: html, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I've created a HTML5 project in the old Cloud 9. I've migrated it to AWS Cloud 9. Now when I select "Run", I get an error, where previously a new tab opened starting the website. How do I fix this?

The error I get is:

```
bash: line 1: index.html: command not found


Process exited with code: 127
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I had to change the runner to `PHP (Build-in web server)`